# Necessary and sufficient conditions of strict local minimum for some specific functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $ f(x) = (x-c)^n g(x)$ and I was working on whether there exist such a necessary and sufficient condition such that $f(x)$ attain its strict local minimum at c .Given the condition that n is odd and $g(c)\not=0$. I was currently thinking that $g(x)$ cannot be continuous at the point c, because if $g(x)$ is continuous at c , it must have a certain value at c, and since it's continuous, we can use the definition of limit to conclude that $f(x)$ is either strictly increasing or decreasing at c . So my assumptions is that $g(x)$ has a jump discontinuity at c with $g(c^-)<0 $ and  $g(c^-)<0 $ if the left and right limit does not go to infinite. And if $g(c^-)$ and $g(c^+)$ goes to infinity, $1/g(c^-)$ and $1/g(c^-) $ are same order infinitesimal with $(x-c)^z$ where $z$ is odd.
Is my assumption correct, because I felt like I'm missing something, or is it that this problem does't even have a necessary and sufficient condition

Comment: g(c) is not equal to zero is one of the condition

Comment: I also forget to note that g(x) might also be some function that don't have a limit at c such as sin(1/x-c)

Comment: I think it's now pretty clear that the necessary condition ca not even be enlisted.